# SQL Server almost duplicate index - which one to delete

Tags: sql-server, indexing, duplicates, include

I have a table with two non-clustered indexes.  Both have the same key columns and both have INCLUDE columns that are the same as well EXCEPT for one column, otherwise they are identical.

I need to drop one as having two almost identical indexes is unnecessary. I'm looking over the Usage Stats and Op Stats that are returned using sp_BlitzIndex.

Usage Stats 
Index A:  Reads: 652,366(652,366 seek) Writes: 3,297,125 
Index B (Has additional column in INCLUDE):  Reads 644,443(640,332 seek 4,111 scan) Writes: 3,897,213

Op Stats 
Index A: 536,711 Singleton Lookups; 1,239,859 scans/seeks; 423,781 deletes; 5,125 updates 
Index B: (Has additional column in INCLUDE):  1,070,124 singleton lookups; 1,225,548 scans/seeks; 913,185 deletes; 5,127 updates.

Index A has more seek reads but less singleton lookups.  My first choice is to keep the index with the additional column (Index B) as I would think it would cover more queries in the long run.  Should I just be focusing on reads only and keep index A?

EDIT:  The table in question has 22 indexes including the two in question which were added by a prior DBA.  Seems unnecessary to have both indexes around when they are so very similar and I'm trying to reduce overhead of so many indexes on this table as it seems to affect performance.  I do realize that proper indexing can be tricky so I guess I'm just asking if the Usage and Op stats I provided should steer me to possibly eliminating one or the other or perhaps neither.

Comment: Don't just focus on the reads. Look at your queries and see which you **need** to cover, and what is not run often enough or is heavy enough to want to avoid a key lookup.

Comment: Thanks Charlieface. The only problem with that is that there are many queries.  This table exists in a warehouse management system so it is touched by a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you "need" to drop one? Unless there is a performance hit due to constant updating of the data thus updating the indexes, both could still provide a benefit for your selects with minimal impact.

Have you ran a trace under normal use and analyzed to see what would benefit you with no indexes?  You can learn a lot about what is going on doing this.